# Node server error

Tags: node.js

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` operating system.

When I run `node -v`, it is showing `v4.2.6`.

When I run `npm -v`, it is showing `3.5.2`.

But when I am trying to run the node server using the command `node server`, it is throwing an error(s). The error is shown below:

```
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angularjs/server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post server file's code here, code details needed to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the `path` from which you are running the server code.
2. And check the `spelling` of your file name you are running and the file that exists in folder i.e., it may be typo error also.

I am sure this error occurs when you are running the code which is not in the path. Go to the path where the folder exists and run the code there.

If you see this image First my file `index.js` file doesn't exists in this path when I run `index.js` I got this error.

[image]

Now I **navigate to a folder** where my `index.js` file exists.When I run `index.js` I got the response

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `node server` try `node server.js` see if that helps.

Make sure you server file has a .js extension as that is what node is looking for.